# Understanding Toast push notifications and how to display text on them and launch app by pressing on them. Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I am trying to set my application to receive toast push notifications from a server.

Since this server in handled by someone else and he did not request the token to the WSN, I followed an example and I am sending the notifications using a "local web page"

```
protected void ButtonSendToast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the URI that the Microsoft Push Notification Service returns to the push client when creating a notification channel.
            // Normally, a web service would listen for URIs coming from the web client and maintain a list of URIs to send
            // notifications out to.
            string subscriptionUri = TextBoxUri.Text.ToString();


            HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Create an HTTPWebRequest that posts the toast notification to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.
            // HTTP POST is the only method allowed to send the notification.
            sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

            // The optional custom header X-MessageID uniquely identifies a notification message. 
            // If it is present, the same value is returned in the notification response. It must be a string that contains a UUID.
            // sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", "<UUID>");

            // Create the toast message.
            string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
               "<wp:Toast>" +
                    "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                    "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                    "<wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>" +
               "</wp:Toast> " +
            "</wp:Notification>";

            // Set the notification payload to send.
            byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

            // Set the web request content length.
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", "EgAdAQMAAAAEgAAAC4AATIYp8fmpjFpbdnRTjf2qfP/GqZ8Bbb62bH6N+0MhSztcV/wXfv9aVjiwbVgF5EX0fgBXC6LvJCpl1+ze7ts9h5je4e1QekryEFqfWl36BtTBnmWqBFk0WmwxpdIgGqhVjAtRdnJ3ODnFSBCfd7dq8nFiFTFDxPcTXhdDbu9W3BKMAFoAjAAAAAAAHFAXTMH+bVbB/m1W60gEAA8AMTkwLjE5My42OS4yMzMAAAAAAF0AbXMtYXBwOi8vcy0xLTE1LTItMTU5OTEyNjk1NS0zODAwNDMxNzQ0LTk2OTg4NTEzNi0xNjkxMDU1MjI4LTcwOTcyNTQ0NC00MDYxNzA4MDczLTI0Mzg0MzM1MzQA"));
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", "wns/toast");


            using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
            }

            // Send the notification and get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
            string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
            string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
            string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

            // Display the response from the Microsoft Push Notification Service.  
            // Normally, error handling code would be here. In the real world, because data connections are not always available,
            // notifications may need to be throttled back if the device cannot be reached.
            TextBoxResponse.Text = notificationStatus + " | " + deviceConnectionStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextBoxResponse.Text = "Exception caught sending update: " + ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Now, in my app, I have requested the channel uri and a handler that is called when this channel receives a push

```
PushNotificationChannel channel = null;

            try
            {
                channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(channel.Uri);
                if (channel.Uri != null)
                {
                    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                    localSettings.Values.Remove("PushToken");
                    localSettings.Values["PushToken"] = channel.Uri;

                    channel.PushNotificationReceived += channel_PushNotificationReceived;

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
}

async void channel_PushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        String notificationContent = String.Empty;

        notificationContent = e.ToastNotification.Content.GetXml();
        Debug.WriteLine(notificationContent);
    }
```

So far, so good: I receive a notification when my app is running and when my app is closed.  But it only says "New notification" and nothing happens when I click on it.

I have tried to add an event

```
e.ToastNotification.Activated += ToastNotification_Activated;
```

But that does not work and after reading like 20 documents I am very confused about the toast templates and how can I use it to display what I receive from the server

So, what is the real way to do this, to display in the toast some of the data received in the push, and to make the app to "launch / go to a certain page" when the user clicks on it?

Comment: did you find a solution to your query regarding navigating to a specific page on Push notification tap by the user?

Answer (score 0):

For app to go to a certain page

*Since Windows 8/8.1, applications has always been expected to handle activations in response to a user clicking on a toast notification from this app – the app should respond by performing navigation and displaying UI specific to the toast. This is accomplished through an activation string that you include in the toast payload, which is then passed to your app as an argument in the activation event.*

for Navigation to certain page you need to override OnActivated event in App.Xaml.cs and and handle to string parameter.

For Display toast
If you want to show text in tiles then it try Badge notifications or only data received through toast then handle it on page after navigation from onactivated event. Also [Check this link](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/windows-notifications-demystified/). It shows standard templates for different notifications. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a "New notification" when the system doesn't recognize your toast notification payload. That's because you used the [MPNS quickstart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx), not the [WNS quickstart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252.aspx) and got most of the stuff moved to WNS except for your toast notification format. You want your toast content to look something like this:

```
<toast launch="">
  <visual lang="en-US">
    <binding template="ToastImageAndText01">
      <image id="1" src="World" />
      <text id="1">Hello</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</toast>
```

Here's the WNS quickstart guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868252.aspx

As well as the WNS toast schema: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230849.aspx